# Axios sending OPTIONS instead GET

Tags: axios

I'm trying to make api calls locally in a react app using axios.

I've already added django-cors-headers and followed the documentation, but it does not seem to be working.

I always get the error:

localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

my base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "todo",
    "api",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    # ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

In my react app:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({})
useEffect(
    () => {
        axios.get(
            api_url, {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                }
            }
        ).then(
            res => {
                setTodos(res.data);
                console.log(res.data)
            }
        ).catch(
            err => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    }, []
)
```

Note, even without configuring a whitelist and reverting the CORS settings to:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I still manage to get the data in a get call using httpie, just running http + url.

Note 2: When the axios tries to get the data, I get this on the terminal running the Django app:

[04/Jun/2019 18:15:29] "OPTIONS /api/todos/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0

IMPORTANT EDIT:
The problem does not seem to be with my server, I used fetch instead of Axios and everything occurred normally. With Axios, my server was getting an OPTIONS method, and, I do not know why, I was giving this problem with CORS.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?